# Docker installation on Raspberry Pi 3 fail not matching kernel version in aufs

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, docker

What has changed lately with the Docker installation on Raspbian that makes Docker installation fail and what can be done about it?

On Raspberry Pi 3, installation of docker from get.docker.com fails with error message:

> Error! The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which 
>   does not match this kernel/arch. This indicates that it should not be built.

I tried editing /usr/src/aufs-4.9+20161219/dkms.conf and removing the line

> BUILD_EXCLUSIVE_KERNEL="^4.9.*"

then running

```
sudo apt-get remove -y docker-engine
sudo apt-get install -y docker-engine
```

which seems to fix the problem as far as I can see but it does seems to be a hack to just remove the check of the kernel version.

```
pi@kubmaster:~ $ uname -a
Linux kubmaster 4.9.41-v7+ #1023 SMP Tue Aug 8 16:00:15 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download Raspbian Stretch Lite from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ with release date 2017-09-07, write image to an SD card, start Rasbian and setup networking.
2. Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
   curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
   chmod +x get-docker.sh
   sudo ./get-docker.sh
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar error. Try to install kernel headers:

```
sudo aptitude install linux-headers-4.9.0-4-all raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

Comment: That worked nicely, both on Raspbian Stretch and Jessie! 

I had tried installing the raspberrypi-kernel-headers but not the linux-headers-4.9.0-4-all.

Thank you @Idanko!

Comment: @JohnAllberg if my solution works, please accept it (click the acceptance mark on the left)